# Why do we assign a value to head in the loop if it's not used?

Tags: java, linked-list, copy-constructor

```
public CarList(CarList cl)
{
    if(cl == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    if (cl.head == null)
        head = null;
    else
    {
        // Notice that you cannot issue head = cl.head; otherwise both heads will point at the passed list;

        head = null;
        // Now create and copy all the nodes in the list
        CarNode temp, temp2, temp3;
        temp = cl.head;
        temp2 = null;
        temp3 = null;


        while(temp != null)
        {
            if (temp2 == null)      // The case for the first node
            {
                temp2 = new CarNode(temp.getCar(), null);
                head = temp2;
            }
            else
            {
                temp3 = new CarNode(temp.getCar(), null);
                temp2.setNext(temp3);
                temp2 = temp3;
            }

            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        // Avoid privacy leak; set all temporary pointers to null 
        temp = temp2 = temp3 = null;
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand what the loop does... I can't parse the code. And does the privacy lea is due to the fact that temp variables hold addresses?

Comment: Er, `head` is used. See this line: `head = temp2;`

Comment: It's never used _in this code_; however, `head` a member field of the `CarList` class and (taking an educated guess) is used elsewhere in the class.

Answer (score 1):

It is used:

```
    head = temp2;
```

Your tags specify exactly what is going on here.  CarList is a class that denotes a singly-linked list, where each element of the list is wrapped up in a CarNode, which contains the element, plus a link to the next element in the list.

The 'head' variable points to the first CarNode in the list.  The while loop in question, while its variable names are questionable, simply copies the argument list into the one being instantiated, making a new CarNode for every element.  Walk through it for a 4 element example and you'll see what it's doing.

It would do you well to look up "Lisp CAR function" for more information.  [This page](http://www.augustana.ab.ca/~mohrj/courses/common/csc370/lecture_notes/lisp2.html) has a good bit of information about it as well.